# Import statement does not work in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I read about import and export declarations in javascript. Then  I'm trying to  import a class in a file using 'import' keyword. But despite having read about the declaration of modules in node.js y get a error when execute node.

My index.ts :

```
import Server from "./classes/server";
import router from './routes/router';

const server = new Server();

server.app.use('/', router);

server.start(() => {
    console.log("server starting!");
})
```

My classes/server.ts

```
import { SERVER_PORT } from './../global/enviroment';
import express from 'express';

class Server {
    public app: express.Application;
    public port: number;

    constructor(){
        this.app = express();
        this.port = SERVER_PORT;
    }

    start(callback: any){
        this.app.listen(this.port, callback);
    }
}
export default Server;
```

My package.json

[image]

But when i try to run `npm run start`...

[image]

Comment: when execute `npm run start` run the command `node .` (i have added the package.json picture to the issue)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How is your tsconfig.json ?

I assume you are missing some configuration that that enables the compilation of the typescript file into a compatible javascript that node can run, here's an example of tsconfig.json that should work

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
}
```

So essentially you will need to have `moduleResolution` to `node`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Also don't forget that node doesn't run ts files, you need to compile then first with tsc. Or if you prefer you can always run `npx ts-node index.ts`

**EDIT**:

ts-node what it does is compile your code first from ts to js  and run it node with the generated js, you can check more information about ts node https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node.

If you want to avoid to use ts-node your can always compile first using `npx tsc` which is the compiler from typescript, once you have the javascript you can run `node index.js` or simply `node .`. 
Note that you have to check  where you're output folder for the js file using the `outDir` on the ts configuration, if `outDir`is configuration is missing will add js files in the same place the ts exists 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Works!. My server its running. But muy tsconfig.json is similar to yours. only i have execute `npx ts-node index.ts`  I didn't know that command. Could you offer me a little more information about that?

Comment: @Monic edited the answer to have links where to check more information about ts-node

Comment: Note: ts-node should not be used in production

Comment: If your project requires other `compilerOptions.module` value (e.g. Next.js requires `"esnext"`), you can do the following: `ts-node --compilerOptions '{"module":"commonjs"}'` to overwrite your _tsconfig.json_.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `import/export` syntax, you have following options:

- use node's native experimental ES modules
- Use `esm` npm package
- Transpile to commonjs using babel or similar tooling.

### Using node's native ES modules:

Add this to your package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

And change your start script to: `"start": "node index.js"` (assumes you're using node > v13.3.0). If you're using node v12 or above, you can try: `node --experimental-modules index.js`

### Use `esm` package:

Docs here: https://github.com/standard-things/esm

---

You need to compile your `.ts` files to `.js` files first though. See [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can't use the import statement in node js yet. But you could use the experimental features(.mjs files).

[This article](https://adrianmejia.com/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond/) explains the module/file imports in detail.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using ts-node and this works for me

```
import {ClassName} from './path/to/file.js/'  //not file.ts
```

even if your file's name is file.ts using file.js works